# What is the difference between Lazy Loading and List Virtualization in React?

Tags: reactjs, performance, lazy-loading

Recently for a project at work I recently implemented Lazy Loading for multiple list components that are being rendered at the same time, which caused performance issues. However, today I came across something on the React Docs called List Virtualization.

The package I'm currently using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload

One of the packages for List Virtualization recommended in the official docs: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

If someone could please explain the difference between the two, I would highly appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Have you just reviewed the source code to see how they are implemented and how they are the same or different? They appear to have fairly similar functionality, although react-virtualized is more of a swiss army knife of virtualization weighing in at 1.13MB versus the 38.6KB of react-lazyload.

Comment: Thank you Drew for taking the time to reply. No, I read the documentation, but haven't looked at the source code yet. I was confused because they both seem very familiar functionality-wise, yet different at the same time, because implementing Lazy Loading results in a few ms of delay before my components show up, but on the website of another package listed on the React docs (https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size) , there doesn't seem to be any delay when using List Virtualization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arriving a bit late to the party, but I'll add my two cents here from what I personally gather is the difference broadly.

The idea of lazy loading is to make asynchronous calls to fetch new data (from an API endpoint, a store, etc) as it appears in the viewport. This improves the user experience as the user does not need to wait for all the data to load at once but only what is needed in the viewport. The social media platform [Triller](https://triller.co/) is a good example of a site that lazily loads content into the viewport to produce an infinite feed as a user scrolls. Lazy loading only concerns itself with fetching subsequent data and loading it into the viewport.

Virtualization is similar but renders only what is in the viewport. As previously fetched data leaves the viewport, so do those DOM nodes. This improves the user experience since a user who scrolls for a very long time would otherwise have many DOM nodes and, as a result, may notice a drop in performance. The social media platform [Instagram](https://instagram.com/) is a good example of a site that makes use of virtualization for its feed. Only a handful of posts will remain loaded in the DOM while a user scrolls.

See diagrams below for a visual representation:

[image: Without Lazy Loading]
[image: With Lazy Loading]

---

[image: With Lazy Loading, User Scrolled]
[image: With Virtualization]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Richard. This is a fantastic explanation! I love that you used diagrams to show the difference between normal loading, lazy loading, and virtualization. It seems that for medium-length lists that a user constantly scrolls up and down, it'd make more sense to use lazy loading since the nodes remain in the DOM, and for long lists (such as the example you used, Instagram) where the user usually scrolls downward and rarely scrolls back up, it makes much more sense to use virtualization.