# Why is so much time spent in scripting when rendering list items in React? (performance optimisation)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to improve the performance of my React app (Electron to be specific) which uses `react-redux` and `reselect`. I have a parent (grid) component which gets some data from the redux store using `useSelector`, and for each item in the array renders a child component (row in the grid). We also have a filter functionality, so we do some transformation on the array of product data. Something along these lines:

```
 const data = useDataSelector(
   "all",
   categoryId || EVERYTHING_CATEGORY_ID
 );
 const location = useLocation();
 const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      setFilteredData(
        fuse.search(`${query}`).map((product) => product.item)
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredData(data);
    }
  }, [
    location.search,
  ])

 return (
   <>
     {data.map((productInfo) => (
            <Row key={productInfo.id} {...productInfo} />
          ))}
   </>
 );
```

`useDataSelector` calls `useSelector`:

```
export const useDataSelector = (statusType: StatusType = "all", categoryId) =>
  useSelector(productSelector(statusType, categoryId));
```

and `productSelector` is a memoized selector that does some pretty heavy computation:

```
const productSelector = (
  statusType: StatusType,
  categoryId: number,
) =>
  createSelector(
    [selectProductData, selectProductStatus],
    (productData, productStatus) =>
    //some pretty heavy computations here
  )
```

Now the issue I am seeing is the fact that rendering the grid component is super slow. I can't really see much when recording performance except for the fact that we're spending a very long time `scripting`:

[image]

I can't see much when looking at the `Call Tree` or `Event Log` tabs. It seems like death by a thousand papercuts... Is this normal? It's rather disappointing how janky our scroll is.

[image]

(regarding the screenshot above: we've added `LazyLoad` to reduce load time when we switch the tabs or when the app is loaded). This guy sets up `scroll` event listener and renders more components when needed.

```
<li>
  <LazyLoad
        height={60}
        scrollContainer={scrollContainer}
        offset={500}
        overflow
        once
  >
    // actual component rendering
  </LazyLoad>
</li>
```

Comment: Might be because you seem to be using an index as a key so React redraws all items. Try using the entry's unique id instead. If there's none, add it explicitly to each entry first.

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately. I've tried `<Row key={productInfo.id} {...productInfo} />`, but `checkVisible` still takes over 1k ms

Comment: Can you show what `useDataSelector` do? And do you have an event listener for the scroll event? Do you use some kind of virtualized list if you grid contains a lot of elements?

Comment: Yeah. I've added the abbreviated implementation of `useDataSelector` in my question above. 

We have an event listener setup inside the `LazyLoad` component from `react-lazyload`. It's also the guy that kicks in when we have many elements. I've also included abbreviated code for this in my question

Comment: you should take a look at virtualization in react, check react-window or react-virtuoso

Comment: It'd go a long way for assisting with this/giving a proper answer if you had runnable code we could explore. Looking at a static image of the react dev tools doesn't particularly help. There's thousands of possibilities right now and we could spend thousands of possibilities running those by you one or two at a time. My current guess is that you are running the Lazy Loading handler on each individual element, which will cause them all to run code to check if they are visible entirely separately. But without more code, I can't tell anything besides a guess.

Comment: How is react-window different to react-lazyload? Don't they do the same thing @guiwme5 ?

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate it's not easy to track performance of a few snippets of code. Unfortunately it's not a project I could share @ZacharyHaber . What you're suggesting sounds very reasonable. I've tried to remove the LazyLoad handler entirely though and it simply makes the entire app hang for some time before loading all items at once rather than give poor scroll performance, i.e. the issue just moves somewhere else :(

Comment: @user3681304 can you set up a minimal viable example that demonstrates the problem that you can share? Data could all be mocked or something. And yeah, rendering thousands of elements is really slow, but running javascript on thousands of individual elements could also be slow. As to LazyLoad vs virtualized, I believe virtualized could solve your issue. Lazy load appears to be more for individual large components rather than thousands of tiny ones. List virtualization is more for rendering thousands of individual list items.

Comment: LazyLoad is to render whole components in background once it gets into the viewport, so you will have all the nodes there once it gets loaded scrolling the viewport, instead virtualization is to render just the part that is inside the viewport (you can set a little more than the view size) but if it is a giant list each node will be in the memory and what virtualization does is release the nodes that already are outside the viewport, so scrolling will release the memory for the nodes already lazy loaded. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63185661/what-is-the-difference-between-lazy

Comment: Right, thanks @guiwme5 for the explanation! We've tried that and it's even worse :( We have very few element: 200 tops. The issue is that they're just being loaded very slowly. When we have LazyLoad, performance is only poor for the first scroll to the very bottom and then pleasantly responsive. When we had react-window scrolling was janky going downards and upwards...

Comment: @ZacharyHaber this would be a good exercise actually and maybe it would help me understand what is going on. It would require quite a significant amount of time as we're fetching the data from 2 APIs, aggregate it and only then use it for rendering. Will also need to anonymize the data, but I'll give it a go!

Comment: 200 elements? 
try mock your data or fetch from another server to see the response timing.

Comment: I did that, I mocked static JSON responses inside the data selector and the performance was still awful...

Comment: can you show more code about your components? what <Row/> is doing? that could be doing something expensive, and put some console.logs to see how many times is rerendering, use react-devtools extension for chrome it gives you some tips why a component is rerendering (props, hooks, useEffects, state changing) then check your props, if they are a new reference for the same fn is unintended rerender. Use the performance tab inside the chrome console shows component delays. If you don't see the component name add this, to each one: MyComponent.displayName = "MyComponent";

Comment: @user3681304 My next guess is that you need to memoize the result of your selector creator before putting it into the code, or you should use [rereselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) which is meant for that purpose. Currently the selector is getting re-created on every render, which means that expensive calculation will occur on every render.

Comment: So I think you've got a pretty good hunch @guiwme5 We actually have multiple useSelector calls inside each of the <Row/> components and inside their nested components. When I added log.count() to the selector calls just a few clicks around the app summed up to about 100k useSelector calls. I think I'll look into this and make sure we don't call them so often 

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot @ZacharyHaber ! I was thinking about something like this, but I didn't know about rereselect. Thanks! Will give it a go!

Comment: Wow, @guiwme5! Your tips have been super helpful! I actually do not know why I have not figured something like this myself, but anyhow: by logging how many times a component is rendered I noticed that whenever I change the tabs there are far too many renders (much more than <Row/>s being displayed). I've also looked at react-devtools and I've noticed that whenever I change tabs, the <Row/>s are re-rendered even if visually nothing changes because "hooks have changed". And this happens because we seem to return the entire world in these hooks and the returned value is bound to change!

Comment: Im glad to read that, if you think was helpful please mark it as the answer, probably you want to understand why you rendering too many times, there is no a general answer, you have to investigate rerendering cases and try to follow the good practices
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/best-practices-for-react/  to furthering on, this other link https://dev.to/dhiwise/10-best-practices-every-react-developer-should-follow-a15 and bonus (to review some concepts, is always a good idea) https://medium.com/@anny.huynh32/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await-a66668d44c7b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Zachary Haber in the comments, you aren't getting the full benefit of `createSelector` because you are creating the memoized selector through a function which gets re-executed on every render.

You can actually [pass arguments through your input selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument), though it's annoying because you have two arguments (and we don't want to combine them into an object without memoizing that object).

You can move the `productSelector` function into the `useDataSelector` hook and wrap it in `useMemo` such that it is only re-evaluated when `statusType` or `categoryId` change.

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'; // or from 'reselect'
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const useDataSelector = (statusType: StatusType = "all", categoryId: number): Product[] => {
  const productSelector = useMemo(() => {
    return createSelector(
      [selectProductData, selectProductStatus],
      (productData, productStatus): Product[] => {
        return heavyComputation(productData, productStatus, statusType, categoryId);
      }
    )
  },
    [statusType, categoryId]
  );

  return useSelector(productSelector);
}
```

If someone visits a `categoryId` then goes to another one then comes back to the first, it **will** re-evaluate with this approach.  Whereas something like `re-reselect` would keep the previously-computed selectors in its cache.

Also note that if you have multiple components using `useDataSelector` they will each create their own cached version of the selector.  I am assuming here that the list is the only place which accesses the data and that all child components get their data passed down via props.

Since `re-reselect` solves these issue, let's see how we can use it.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createCachedSelector } from 're-reselect';

const productSelector = createCachedSelector(
  // select from redux state
  selectProductData,
  selectProductStatus,
  // pass through arguments
  (state: RootState, statusType: StatusType) => statusType,
  (state: RootState, statusType: StatusType, categoryId: number) => categoryId,
  // combine the results
  (productData, productStatus, statusType, categoryId): Product[] => {
    return heavyComputation(productData, productStatus, statusType, categoryId);
  }
)(
  // create a unique cache key from our arguments
  (state, statusType, categoryId) => `${statusType}__${categoryId}`
)

export const useDataSelector = (statusType: StatusType = "all", categoryId: number): Product[] => {
  return useSelector((state: RootState) => productSelector(state, statusType, categoryId));
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W48bAW)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to memoize the generated rows too.

```
  const rows = useMemo(
    () => data.map((productInfo, idx) => <Row key={idx} {...productInfo} />),
    [data]
  );
  return rows;
```

And the react docs recommend not to use indexes as keys in list elements. You should change that to use any identifier in your `productInfo` data; perhaps you have `productInfo.id`?

Comment: Thanks @diedu for your suggestion. I've tried using the product id before and it didn't make a difference. I'll try the memo thing, although I did give memoization a go in some other form and it didn't help either. Will check this though and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I have to admit @diedu that I oversimplified my sample regarding your suggestion. 'data' is not used directly to render rows. There is actually one other variable that holds the result of filtering the product data (switching tabs, handling search). I'll update my question tomorrow to include it, but basically we're not really doing 'data.map', but rather 'filteredDataResult.map', which changes as user interacts with the UI. And thus memoization does not help here (I've just verified it too) :(